# Access AWS CodeCommit from TeamCity

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, teamcity, aws-codecommit

I cannot figure out how to add [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) git repository to TeamCity on Windows. I tried both SSH and HTTP based integration and it doesn't work either way (I get 403 errors). HTTP is a more viable option but since AWS instruction is suggesting to use Putty's Pageant, I think that causes an issue when TeamCity is running as a Windows service.

I appreciate a hint if you've made it to work or have any suggestion.

Comment: CodeCommit announced Git Credentials last week. You should now be able to generate static credentials for your IAM user and use them to connect CodeCommit repository with Teamcity. Please see this for more info: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/aws-codecommit-introduces-git-credentials-for-user-authentication/

Answer (score 4):

TeamCity does not currently support git credential helpers, which is required for CodeCommit over HTTPS.

To set up SSH access, associate an SSH key with an IAM user ([instructions here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-without-cli.html#setting-up-without-cli-add-key)).  You can then upload the SSH key to the TeamCity server ([instructions here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/SSH+Keys+Management)). For TeamCity's git authentication settings ([see here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Git#Git-AuthenticationSettings)), use "Private Key" with the uploaded key and enter the SSH key ID from the AWS IAM console as the username.